# How To config $routeProvider with 'app.config' no longer in Express 4? (Angular JS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express

The problem I'm having is **app.config** is said to be the only block where **$routeProvider** can be called. With Express 4 removing app.config, how should it be called now?

Previously :

```
    var app = angular.module('sampleApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/home.html'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
}]);
```

Express 4 is now asking that we use process.env.NODE_ENV to configure, if so, how would this be rewritten?

Are there other ways?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Took me too long to realize I don’t really have a problem here. I just downgraded my Express version. If anybody comes across this looking for answers too, unless you’re dependent on something in Express 4 just downgrade. duh *facepalm*